# How to regex replace a query string with matching 2 words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url and I want to replace the query string. For example

`www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200`

I want to match the `wid=` and `hei=` and the numbers don't have to be `200` to replace the whole thing so it should look like this.

Expected
`www.test.com/is/images/383773?@HT_dtImage`

So I've tried doing but it only replaced the matching `wei` and `hei`.

```
const url = "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200"

url.replace(/(wid)(hei)_[^\&]+/, "@HT_dtImage")
```

Comment: e.g. start with something explicit and readable like ...  [`(wid|hei)=[^&]+&(hei|wid)=[^&\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/GStypH/1) ... which could but does not necessarily has to be refactored into something shorter like that ... [`(?:&?(?:hei|wid)=[^&\s]+){2}`](https://regex101.com/r/GStypH/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match either wid= or hei= until the next optional ampersand and then remove those matches, and then append `@HT_dtImage` to the result.

```
\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:wid|hei)=` Non capture group, match either `wid` or `hei` followed by `=`
- `[^&]*&?` Match 0+ times a char other than `&`, and then match an optional `&`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LC0c2I/1).

```js
let url = "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200"
url = url.replace(/\b(?:wid|hei)=[^&]*&?/g, "") + "@HT_dtImage";
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use string split here:

```js
var url = "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200";
var output = url.split("?")[0] + "?@HT_dtImage";
console.log(output);
```

If you only want to target query strings havings both keys `wid` and `hei`, then use a regex approach:

```js
var url = "www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200";
var output = url.replace(/(.*)\?(?=.*\bwid=\d+)(?=.*\bhei=\d+).*/, "$1?@HT_dtImage");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of lookaround using regex `/\?.*/`

[image]

```js
const url = 'www.test.com/is/images/383773?wid=200&hei=200';

const result = url.replace(/\?.*/, '?@HT_dtImage');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
`url.replace(/\?.*/, "?@HT_dtImage")`

Comment: It would help if you explained what this does and why

Comment: \?.* = select everything from questionmark and to the end of line
then replace it with ?@HT_dtImage